# CastException while using Decimal? type

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, data-binding

in my scenario i need to bind Decimal? type property to Double? type property.

Here is the simple code using Double?

```
public class Model
    {
        private double? id = null;
        public double? ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value;  }
        }
    }
```

and my Xaml

```
 <TextBox x:Name="db" Width="100"  Height="{Binding Path=ID}" />
```

this works without any issues,
but if i change type of ID as Decimal? like,

```
 public class Model
    {
        private decimal? id = null;
        public decimal? ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value;  }
        }
    }
```

it throws exception(need to enable all exception in VS). is there any specific reason behind this behavior ?

exception details :

> System.InvalidCastException occurred   _HResult=-2147467262
>   _message=Null object cannot be converted to a value type.   HResult=-2147467262   IsTransient=false   Message=Null object cannot
>   be converted to a value type.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)   InnerException:

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: @Clemens i forgot to mention that we have to enable all exceptions

Comment: @Clemens VS -> Debug -> Exception-> check all thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the reason is what's written in the exception:

> Null object cannot be converted to a value type

When it tries to make a double value (for the "Height" property) out of your decimal, the conversion method ("System.Convert.ChangeType") does not know how to deal with a null(able) value. Since this method never gets called when the type of the property ("double?") and the binding property ("ID") are of the same type, you never encounter this error in your original environment.

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

And use this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="db" Width="100"  Height="{Binding ID, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"/>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks,,i just need a reason for this behavior